# ngOnInit is not being called (but constructor and ngOnDestroy are being called as expected) when navigated to child components

Tags: angular

I have a component `ViewBotsComponent` which is having 2 child components: `ViewCodeBasedBotComponent` and `ViewPipelineBasedBotsComponent`.

I route them as follows:

```
const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: "core", component: CoreWrapperComponent, children:[
      {path: 'viewbots', component: ViewBotsComponent, children:
          [
            {path: 'codebased', component: ViewCodeBasedBotComponent},
            {path: 'intelligent', component: ViewPipelineBasedBotsComponent},
            // {path: '', component: ViewCodeBasedBotComponent}
          ]
      }
  },
  ...
]
```

When I go toggle between `http://localhost:4200/core/viewbots/codebased` and `http://localhost:4200/core/viewbots/intelligent`, `constructor` and `ngOnDestroy` are being called for child components as expected **but `ngOnit` is not being called**.

Now where it gets weirder: **If I reload my browser tab, everything works fine and

ngOnInit is being called as expected.**

Following is the 30 sec video of issue, notice that  ngOninit is not being logged initially but after reloading it is being logged:
https://youtu.be/_HCh3eJAX9I

---

Following is my code:

**Parent component html: (view-bots.component.html)**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs my-2">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'tab-active':activeTab==='codebased'}" (click)="changeActiveTab('codebased')" ><strong>CODE BASED BOTS</strong></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'tab-active':activeTab==='intelligent'}" (click)="changeActiveTab('intelligent')" ><strong>PIPELINE BASED BOTS</strong></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Parent component ts: (view-bots.component.ts)**

```
export class ViewBotsComponent implements OnInit {

  botList$: Observable<IBot[]>;
  activeTab:string = "codebased";

  constructor(
    private serverService: ServerService,
    private constantsService: ConstantsService,
    private router:Router,
    private store: Store) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ViewBotsComponent init');
  }
  changeActiveTab(activeTab){
    console.log("hi");
    this.router.navigate(['core','viewbots',activeTab]);
    this.activeTab =activeTab

  }
}
```

**Child1 html: view-pipeline-based-bots.component.html**

```
<p>pipelineBasedBotList</p>
```

**Child1 ts: view-pipeline-based-bots.component.ts**

```
export class ViewPipelineBasedBotsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('pipelineBasedBotList destroyed');
  }

  constructor() {
    console.log("ViewPipelineBasedBotsComponent constructor")
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('pipelineBasedBotList init');
  }

}
```

**Child2 html: view-code-based-bot.component.html**

```
<p>ViewCodeBasedBotComponent</p>
```

**Child2 ts: view-code-based-bot.component.ts**

```
export class ViewCodeBasedBotComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    console.log("ViewCodeBasedBotComponent constructor")
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("ViewCodeBasedBotComponent init")
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log("ViewCodeBasedBotComponent destroyed")
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: "core", component: CoreWrapperComponent, children:[
      {path: 'viewbots', component: ViewBotsComponent, children:
          [
            {path: 'codebased', component: ViewCodeBasedBotComponent},
            {path: 'intelligent', component: ViewPipelineBasedBotsComponent},
            // {path: '', component: ViewCodeBasedBotComponent}
          ]
      },
      {path: 'botdetail', component: BotDetailWrapperComponent, children:
          [
            {path: 'codebased/:id', component: CodeBasedBotDetailComponent},
            {path: 'intelligent/:id', component: PipelineBasedBotDetailComponent},
          ]
      },
      {path: 'analytics', component: WrapperComponent, children:
          [
            {path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent},
            {path: 'users', component: UsersComponent},
            {path: 'sessions', component: SessionsComponent},
            {path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent},
            {path: 'platforms', component: PlatformsComponent},
            {path: 'events', component: EventsComponent},
            {path: 'engagement', component: EngagementComponent},
            {path: 'usage', component: UsageComponent}
          ]
      },

      {path: 'customner', component: ViewCustomnerComponent},
      {path: 'customner/create', component: CreateCustomnerComponent},
      {path: 'enterpriseprofile', component: EnterpriseprofileComponent},
      {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
      {path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent},
      {path: 'documentation', component: DocumentationComponent},
      // {path: 'buildbot/codebased', component: BuildCodeBasedBotComponent},
      // {path: 'buildbot/intelligent', component: BuildPipelineBasedBotComponent},
      {path: 'buildbot', component: BuildbotWrapperComponent, children:
          [
            {path: 'codebased', component: BuildCodeBasedBotComponent},
            {path: 'intelligent', component: BuildPipelineBasedBotComponent},
            {path: '', component: ViewCodeBasedBotComponent}
          ]
      },
      // {path: 'viewbots/codebased', component: ViewCodeBasedBotComponent},
      // {path: 'viewbots/intelligent', component: ViewPipelineBasedBotsComponent},
      {path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},

      {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
    ],
  },
  {path: "auth", component: AuthWrapperComponent, children: [
      {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
      {path:'auth', component: SignupComponent}
    ]},
  {path: '',  redirectTo: 'core/viewbots/codebased',pathMatch: 'full'},
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    ViewBotsComponent,
    ViewCodeBasedBotComponent,
    ViewPipelineBasedBotsComponent,
    BotPreviewCardComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    BuildCodeBasedBotComponent,
    BuildPipelineBasedBotComponent,
    RouterFragmentActiveDirective,
    BasicInfoFormComponent,
    AvatorFormComponent,
    PipelineComponent,
    KnowledgeBaseComponent,
    CodeInputComponent,
    IntegrationOptionListComponent,
    CodeEditorComponent,
    IntegrationItemComponent,
    DraggableDirective,
    DropTargetDirective,
    DocumentationComponent,
    ViewCustomnerComponent,
    CreateCustomnerComponent,
    OverviewComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    SessionsComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    PlatformsComponent,
    EventsComponent,
    EngagementComponent,
    UsageComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    EnterpriseprofileComponent,
    WrapperComponent,
    ReportsComponent,
    ChartComponent,
    BuildbotWrapperComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    CoreWrapperComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    AuthWrapperComponent,
    PipelineTestComponent,
    BotDetailComponent,
    HandsontableComponent,
    SmartTableComponent,
    BotDetailWrapperComponent,
    CodeBasedBotDetailComponent,
    PipelineBasedBotDetailComponent,
    BotTestingComponent,
    ConsumersComponent,
    SessionComponent,
    BotSessionsComponent,
    ChatWrapperComponent,
    ChatWindowComponent,
    ChatMessageComponent,
    BotWelcomeComponent,
    ChatListComponent,
    ChatItemComponent,
    ChatroomComponent,
    ScrollerDirective,
    ReportDetailsComponent,
    ReportDisplayComponent,
    ReportControlsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes), // RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }), if this is your app.module
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    AceEditorModule,
    UiSwitchModule,
    FormsModule,
    DragAndDropModule.forRoot(),
    ChartModule,
    NgxsModule.forRoot([AuthStateReducer,
      NavigationStateReducer,
      AppStateReducer,
      EnterpriseprofileStateReducer,
      ViewBotStateReducer,
      ChatSessionStateReducer,
      BotCreationStateReducer,
      AnalysisStateReducer
    ]),
    NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsLoggerPluginModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    DragulaModule,
    HotTableModule,
    Ng2CompleterModule,
    Ng2SmartTableModule,
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [DragService, AimService,{
    provide: NGXS_PLUGINS,
    useValue: persistPlugin,
    multi: true
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: When you use a param, and change from (ex) /users/1 to /users/2 the user component will not be destroyed in between. Which means ngOnInit will be called the first time open the UserComponent but not everytime you display another user. Instead you should subscribe to the ActivatedRoute (there's a params argument which is an observable) and from here you can do what you want every time the user changes.

Comment: But I am not using param in route at all here. I know very similar issue comes up when using route params. There is an SO question for this as well. But in my code I am not using route params at all.